# Adding 2 loops for blocking Memory bandwidth improvement?

Tags: optimization, memory-management, cpu-architecture

The given code have one blocking loop

the code is

```
for (body1 = 0; body1 < NBODIES; body1 ++) {
   for (body2=0; body2 < NBODIES; body2++) {
     OUT[body1] += compute(body1, body2);
   }
}
```

the **one loop** blocking is

```
for (body2 = 0; body2 < NBODIES; body2 += BLOCK) {
   for (body1=0; body1 < NBODIES; body1 ++) {
      for (body22=0; body22 < BLOCK; body22 ++) {
         OUT[body1] += compute(body1, body2 + body22);
      }
   }
}
```

What will be the **two outer loops** that process calculations **blockwise**?

Comment: So `compute()` is doing 2D array indexing with its args?  You don't show that in the question.  Anyway, see my comments on your previous question for loop-tiling examples.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241994/multithreading-and-memory-bandwidth-improvement#comment81435129_47241994

Comment: The code is taken from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cache-blocking-techniques BTW

Comment: Yes, I take code from that link, but I need the 2 loop-tiling for the given nested loops.?